# iPad Music App Crashing

Tags: ipad, music

I have a first generation iPad 32GB WiFi model (MB293LL) running iOS 5.1.1.

I haven't used the Music app for some time; I generally listen to Pandora.  However, I recently bought some music on iTunes and wanted to listen to it.  I cannot get the Music app to run.  It opens, but all I see is the basic app frame and controls - no content - and then it crashes.  I've tried rebooting the iPad and it doesn't fix the issue.

I'd like a solution, or at least some further troubleshooting steps, that I can try other than "backup your data and reset the device".  If anyone has any suggestions, I would sure appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried to resync it with iTunes? Is it a jailbroken device? What about memory space left on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to delete all music and videos, disable Match, and then re-enable/sync from Match.  Glad it was not more destructive.

Comment: Don't forget to mark your question as answered !

Comment: I will, but I'm not able to answer my own question for another 24 hours I believe.